# DreamWeaver CS5.5 and TortoiseSVN simultaniously?

Tags: tortoisesvn, development-environment, dreamweaver

In my web/PHP development I use DreamWeaver CS5.5 as my IDE, TortoseSVN as SVN client, and a local LAMP server ([EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/)) for testing/viewing. These three are treated distinctively in my everyday use:

- Dreamweaver is only used to do the actual coding.
- Windows Explorer is used to browse the tree and open files, as well as updating and comitting through Tortoise.
- My ordinary web browser is used to access the site in development on the local LAMP host

I have two large monitors and feel that I have a decent work flow. But I suspect that I'm "stuck" with how I've always done it, and that there may be better and more efficient ways to work.

Recently I have been looking at DreamWeavers "site" concept and SVN integration. Tried to define a site, with the already existing WC of my trunk folder as "Local Site Folder", and the corresponding SVN URL in the "Version Control" settings. That did not work very well. Suddenly, all folders appeared as modified in TortoiseSVN. The two clients does not seem to keep good track of the updates/comitts in the other one.

Any advice/best practice on how to use DreamWeaver and SVN? Ss it possible to use TortoiseSVN at the same time? (After all TortoiseSVN seems superior to do tagging/branching, edit image files etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to use both Tortoise and DW's internal svn at the same time but it's going to involve some adjustments on how you do things and probably isn't a particularly good idea.

When you first set up Dreamweaver's svn, it does set some bits on your files for its own use and that resulted in what you saw through Tortoise.  If you continue to use DW you sort of have to use the check in and check out buttons to Commit and Update respectively.  Using Tortoise to do it usually results in DW complaining at best or not recognizing the repository at worst.  In short, it's probably better to just use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll drop the SVN in Dreamweaver then. Maybe I shoould gice Eclipse+Subversive or Netbeans a shot instead.

Comment: Unless you have a burning need to use a WYSIWYG interface or need to rely on DW built in behaviors, then Eclipse may be a better choice.

Comment: I've never used the WYSIWYG in DW, so I'll give Eclipse a shot. Does Subversive and TortoiseSVN get along nicely?

Comment: They should.  I've never run both of them on the same repo at the same time but most everything is designed for some level of interoperability with the obvious exception of the DW svn stuff